# Covert a .EASM solid work edrawing file to .WRL

Tags: solidworks

I was wondering if anyone new of any software that could convert .EASM (Solid Works Edrawing) to a .WRL (VRML) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidworks itself can save to a VRML file so if you have the original Solidworks files then you can always save to VRML directly.

Bits online suggest that EASM files are somehow "[broken](http://www.mcadcentral.com/solidworks/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=1578&PN=18&get=last)" and cannot be exported easily to other formats.  eDrawings seems to be the [only application that will open EASM files](http://www.ehow.com/how_5779021_read-file-extension-_easm.html) and you cannot export the file to anything but basic pictures or another eDrawing file...

Answer (score 2):

.easm files are intentionally nonconvertible so that they can only be viewed and the design can't be stolen. 
If the file was created with the "allow save" setting enabled, it can be saved as an STL file, which can then be opened with Solidworks or other 3D CAD software.